# Importing excel-export for aurelia-slickgrid

Tags: aurelia

If have an ESNext Aurelia project and I'm trying to implement the excel export feature for aurelia-slickgrid. When I use the import statement described in the documentation:

```
import { ExcelExportService } from '@slickgrid-universal/excel-export';
```

I get an error that it can't be resolved, which makes sense to me because it doesn't point to anything.

Any help would be appreciated,

Ross

Comment: it's now an optional package, you need to install it yourself ;)  You should also take a look at the migration guide [here](https://github.com/ghiscoding/aurelia-slickgrid/wiki/Migration-to-3.x), if that is not clear enough then I'm open to any changes to the Wikis, thanks

Comment: I've added another bullet in the [HOWTO - Step by Step](https://github.com/ghiscoding/aurelia-slickgrid/wiki/HOWTO--Step-by-Step#11-add-optional-feature-like-excel-export) to provide more info about it and also updated the Excel Export Wiki, that should be clearer now

Comment: That was it!  Thank you.